# After migrating the development DB and the Parse Server, is it possible to migrate the production DB?

Tags: ios, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, parse-server, mlab

i'm now trying to migrate my parse db to a mLab with a parse server hosting it in AWS Elastick Beanstalk.

While migrating, I had few pending problems and i will be glad if you know about these questions.

1. After migrating the DB, will the parse server that is hosted by
   Parse.api.com will continue connecting to the DB that is migrated?
2. After deploying my development DB and parse server to mongoLab and AWS, will the parse.api.com with the production DB still remains running with the app that is used by the user?
3. After migrating the development DB and also the Parse Server to AWS, is it possible to migrate the prduction DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. After migrating the DB, will the parse server that is hosted by
>      Parse.api.com will continue connecting to the DB that is migrated?

That is correct, api.parse.com will hit your self-hosted database for as long as you don't delete the app on parse.com/close your Parse account or until Parse shuts down in January 2017.

Should you chose to delete the app on parse.com, all users that haven't updated to a version of your app that uses your own Parse Server will be left with a broken app until they install the update of your app.

> 2. After deploying my development DB and parse server to mongoLab and AWS, will the parse.api.com with the production DB still remains
>      running with the app that is used by the user?

Assuming that your development and production Parse Apps are two different apps on Parse you will need to migrate them separately and yes, if you only migrate your development app (let's call it App A for now), App B (your production app) won't be effected until you migrate it as well. Of course any non-migrated app will stop working all-together at the end of January 2017.

> 3. After migrating the development DB and also the Parse Server to AWS, is it possible to migrate the production DB?

You are free to migrate as many databases/apps you want. So the answer is yes, you can migrate your production/development versions as well.